# entryset vs keyset in java collection

Tags: java, collections

Which one better for Performance 
*entryset() OR keyset()* in Java Collection ?

**(I) Using enrtySet() in for each loop**

```
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : testMap.entrySet()) {
  entry.getKey();
  entry.getValue();`enter code here`
}
```

**(II) Using keySet() in for each loop**

```
for (String key : testMap.keySet()) {
  testMap.get(key);`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't make much of a difference, but if you need to iterate over both keys and values, use `entrySet` instead of making extra `get` calls.

Answer (score 7):

It really depends on your requirements. Those sets simply represent three different *use cases*: if your "iterating" code

- needs only keys, iterate [keySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--)
- needs access to key + value; use [entrySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--)
- needs the values, use [values()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--)

That's it. Meaning: when you just want to print the *value* of the map, there is no point in working on iterating keys and then *getting* values for example.

If you need both key+value, I would recommend for *clarity* to use `entrySet()`. Don't worry about performance until you run into real issues. And then start **benchmarking** your code to understand what happens.

Comment: I am storing 20 lacs key value pairs in map and will iterate over map and I will also fetch key and value from map for all 20 lacs entries So plz let me know which one is better ?

Comment: See my updates. And for the record - understand that few people out of Asia know what a "lac" is.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `keySet()` iteration can be much slower than `entrySet()` if HashMap contains a lot of collisions.